# Which actions button can fire in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I just attempted a quiz and had following question.

**Which of the following statements are true?**

1. A Button can fire an ActionEvent.
2. A Button can fire a MouseEvent.
3. A Button can fire a KeyEvent.
4. A TextField can fire an ActionEvent.

I selected the first two options but it says wrong. The button ActionEvent and MouseEvent can be placed on button but not the KeyEvent.

What are the right answers?

Comment: Don't tell me the quiz didn't have any study material. Please go over your study material and do your homework by yourself.

Comment: @tanjir When I post here, It means I went through everything. I did my research, I studied the book, I searched internet and I read the presentations. Finally, I posted here to understand what was my mistake because after submission still I don't know the right answer.

Comment: All four of those are true statements, as you can easily verify by writing some code.

Comment: @James_D Thanks. It means the button will take action when the keyboard button is pressed?

Comment: Any node generates a key event if it has the keyboard focus when a key is pressed/released/typed. Again, just write some code to test it. It will take 2 minutes.

Comment: And I guess technically any node can fire any event, via the `Event.fireEvent(...)` method. But that's probably not what the question really meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All four statements are true, as you can verify with some test code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EventTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        TextField textField = new TextField();

        button.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> System.out.println("Key press on button"));
        button.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> System.out.println("Mouse press on button"));
        button.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, e -> System.out.println("Action on button"));
        textField.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, e -> System.out.println("Action on text field"));

        VBox root = new VBox(10, textField, button);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(24));
        primaryStage.setScene( new Scene(root) );
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The explanation and example really helped me to understand all four types.

Answer (score 1):

All of those answers are true. You just need to map the correct events and actions on them.